# My default SSH identity key file was removed after Unbuntu 20.04 udpate

Tags: linux, ssh

I use SSH to access my NUC. Before updating the OS, I could login without issue. After update, I am getting a 'Permission denied (publickey)' error. I can see the necessary key file on my computer. It seems like the identity file path was erased after the update. How can I reset the default identity file to be used upon SSH'ing in?

```
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
xxx@192.xxx.1.112: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `ls ~/.ssh/id_*` I would imagine that your RSA/DSA keys still exist. For example, on my system:

```
.ssh/id_ed25519  .ssh/id_ed25519.pub  .ssh/id_rsa  .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

**Under some circumstances your older DSA/RSA keys may be omitted by default from the key exchange.**

You can create and install new ed25519 keys easily enough:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
ssh-copy-id {remote_host}
```

Or you can allow the reference to your older key (either on the command-line as in this example, or by adding it to the relevant section in `~/.ssh/config`)

```
ssh -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa {remote_host}
```

Comment: Alright so I think I found my issue. I had to re-add the SSH key with `ssh-add` and then I could login as normal. Is it expected to have to `ssh-add` each time a new shell is opened? If so, is there a way to persistently add it to keep from having to add it manually each time?

Comment: I don't use `ssh-add` myself, but I'm sure it's not usual to have to repeat this step each time you want a new session