# Access to Linux server still requires password after setup authorized_keys

Tags: linux, ssh, key-authentication

I have both manually set up the `authorized_keys` and using `ssh-copy-id`, but it still requires the password.

I have made sure my home directory has `755`, the `.ssh` has `700` and `authorized_keys` has `600`

Here the results from `ssh` into serve with `-v` flag

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for remote-server-address
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to remote-server-address port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to remote-server-address:22 as '<user>'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:l8cu8MFiCtU7S/NIXWIOHeiWZItESeWNsWXa4GoJ8SM
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'remote-server-address' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:A2sKd8h69vcMxWwS8IY7Wloe81lv8drWQbKUCYIpqv4
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:A2sKd8h69vcMxWwS8IY7Wloe81lv8drWQbKUCYIpqv4
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `.ssh` on the client and server?

Comment: @FelixJN did you read the question?

Comment: You should have provided your sshd_config from the server, *particularly* the setting for AuthenticationMethods

Comment: @symcbean Yes, I did. Wrong permissions of/in the `.ssh`-directory are often not displayed per se in `-v` and often lead to failed use of pubkey authentication. What is wrong with examining that option?

Comment: ...because the output shows that the ssh client is able to read the files in ~/.ssh on the client AND ssh_copy_id would fail (which also implies the server is writeable)

Comment: @symcbean but it doesn't check whether the server side file's permissions are sufficiently restricitive for sshd to consider them. I'd recommend working together with the people trying to help you, not in confrontation!

Comment: @symcbean No. If `.ssh` is set to e.g. `777` beforehand, `ssh-copy-id` succeeds, but the key-based login afterwards will fail. Kindly feel free to test this.

Comment: This is most often indicative of over-relaxed permissions either on the server or the client. On the server side, reading the messages written to a file such as  `/var/log/auth.log` can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My default SSH identity key file was removed after Unbuntu 20.04 udpate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679782/my-default-ssh-identity-key-file-was-removed-after-unbuntu-20-04-udpate)

Comment: @FelixJN permission of `.ssh` for client and server are both `drwx------`

Comment: @ZepengHuo Please also ensure this for the for the `authorized_keys` file. (server side)

Comment: @symcbean there's no `AuthenticationMethods` in `sshd_config`, but I do have `#PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Comment: @FelixJN the `authorized_keys` on the server side is `-rw-------`

Comment: Switch on debug logging on the server and check the server logs.

Comment: @MartinSchröder you mean `/var/log/auth.log`? I can't find any debug logging. But in that file it does say `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory` but I have made sure my home directory has `755`, the `.ssh` has `700` and `authorized_keys` has `600`

Comment: The error message should say `bad ownership or modes for directory <path>`, indicating the exact directory `sshd` is unhappy about. You've checked the home directory, the `~/.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file; if your home directory is `/home/username`, you must now ensure that the `/`and `/home` directories are not writeable by anyone other than root. Check with `ls -ld / /home`, and if necessary, fix the ownership/permissions with `chown root: / /home; chmod 755 / /home`.

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you added correct public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ?
This lines

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/<user>-l/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:A2sKd8h69vcMxWwS8IY7Wloe81lv8drWQbKUCYIpqv4
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

seem to indicate that your key has been rejected...